# UserForm. How to create it and use data inserted in it by user in macro

Tags: vba, excel

I need to create a UserForm. It would have 3 controls:
1)Label: 'Please denote year'
2)TextBox: '*Here user would insert the year*'
3)CommandButton: '*After clicking it the year would be submitted*'

The year inserted by user would be used in my macro, here is a piece of code with place where the inserted year should be used marked with a comment:

```
            For i = startrow To endrow

            Range("A" & i, "C" & i).Copy
            Sheets("Sheet13").Range("B" & i + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            Range("D" & i).Copy
            Sheets("Sheet13").Range("G" & i + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            Range("H" & i).Copy
            Sheets("Sheet13").Range("H" & i + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            Sheets("Sheet13").Range("E" & i + 1).Value = "Inventory"
            Sheets("Sheet13").Range("F" & i + 1).Value = "31/12/2013" 'Here should be used the inserted year. I don't want to set the value to "31/12/2013?" but to "31/12/'Inserted Year'"
            Sheets("Sheet13").Range("O" & i + 1).Value = "R"

            Next
```

Moreover I would like to ask how to make my macro start to work after clicking the CommandButton in the UserForm.

Many thanks in advance,
with best regards,
Artur Rutkowski

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to run the macro when you click the command button, you simply place the macro inside the command button inside the userform.

You can double click your command button, in the editor, and paste in your code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
startrow = 1
endrow = 4
  For i = startrow To endrow
    Range("A" & i, "C" & i).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet13").Range("B" & i + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Range("D" & i).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet13").Range("G" & i + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Range("H" & i).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet13").Range("H" & i + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Sheets("Sheet13").Range("E" & i + 1).Value = "Inventory"
    Sheets("Sheet13").Range("F" & i + 1).Value = "31/12/2013" 'Here should be used the inserted year. I don't want to set the value to "31/12/2013?" but to "31/12/'Inserted Year'"
    Sheets("Sheet13").Range("O" & i + 1).Value = "R"

  Next
End Sub
```

There are options in the right combobox for click, Dblclick, Enter, Exit, so on...

Comment: Ok, Thank you. That helps me. But how do I use the data inserted into the UserForm in my code?

Comment: I believe you would want to use textbox#.value, where the # represents textbox1 or 2 or whatever you have it named. For example; Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O" & i + 1).Value = TextBox1.Value